# Oracle: Self join XMLTable output

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression, self-join, xmltable

I'm trying to parse some XML into a table in a WITH clause, then in the main query, join that table to itself. However, I get no records, even with a minimal test case.

Here is sample xml:

```
<xml> 
  <entry timestamp="20170330100429" effective="20170329"> 
    <field name="Name"> 
      <ov> <![CDATA[Fran]]> </ov> 
      <nv> <![CDATA[Frank]]> </nv> 
    </field> 
    <field name="Zip"> 
      <ov> <![CDATA[13583]]> </ov> 
      <nv> <![CDATA[13853]]> </nv> 
    </field> 
  </entry> 
  <entry timestamp="20170401094783" effective="20170331"> 
    <field name="MI"> 
      <ov> <![CDATA[J]]> </ov> 
      <nv> <![CDATA[A]]> </nv> 
    </field> 
    <field name="Suffix"> 
      <ov> <![CDATA[Jr]]> </ov> 
      <nv> <![CDATA[III]]> </nv> 
    </field> 
  </entry> 
</xml>
```

Here is stripped-down SQL to flatten the XML into a table in a WITH clause:

```
with myxml as
(
  select 1 xml_id,
         '<xml> <entry timestamp="20170330100429" effective="20170329"> <field name="Name"> <ov><![CDATA[Fran]]></ov> <nv><![CDATA[Frank]]></nv> </field> <field name="Zip"> <ov><![CDATA[13583]]></ov> <nv><![CDATA[13853]]></nv> </field> </entry> <entry timestamp="20170401094783" effective="20170331"> <field name="MI"> <ov><![CDATA[J]]></ov> <nv><![CDATA[A]]></nv> </field> <field name="Suffix"> <ov><![CDATA[Jr]]></ov> <nv><![CDATA[III]]></nv> </field> </entry> </xml>' x from dual
),
HRH as
(
SELECT au.xml_id,
       ts.tran_ts as chg_timestr,
       to_date(substr(ts.tran_ts, 0, 8), 'yyyymmdd') chg_date,
       cast(substr(ts.tran_ts, 9, 6) as int) chg_time,
       f.fieldname,
       f.ov old_value,
       f.nv new_value
  FROM myxml au,
     xmltable('/xml'
              PASSING XMLTYPE(au.x)
              COLUMNS entrynode XMLTYPE PATH 'entry'
     ) as x1,
     xmltable('/entry'
              PASSING x1.entrynode
              COLUMNS tran_ts   VARCHAR(16) PATH '@timestamp',
                      fieldnode XMLTYPE     PATH 'field'
     ) as ts,
     xmltable('/field'
              PASSING ts.fieldnode
              COLUMNS fieldname VARCHAR(250) PATH '@name',
                      nv VARCHAR(250) PATH 'nv',
                      ov VARCHAR(250) PATH 'ov'
     ) as f
)
select * from HRH
```

This query gives the following output:

```
XML_ID CHG_TIMESTR    CHG_DATE   CHG_TIME FIELDNAME OLD_VALUE NEW_VALUE
====== ============== ========== ======== ========= ========= =========
     1 20170330100429 2017-03-30   100429 Name      Fran      Frank    
     1 20170330100429 2017-03-30   100429 Zip       13583     13853    
     1 20170401094783 2017-04-01    94783 MI        J         A        
     1 20170401094783 2017-04-01    94783 Suffix    Jr        III     
====== ============== ========== ======== ========= ========= =========
```

If instead, I use either of the following:

```
select * from HRH h1, HRH h2
select * from HRH h1 join HRH h2 on 1=1
```

I get an error messages:

```
Line Pos Text
==== === ================================================
17   23  ORA-19032: Expected XML tag , got no content
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 1
==== === ================================================
```

How can I get this to work? My overall goal is to get the most recent update to a given xml_id-field combination for my dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure quite why you're seeing that behaviour; materializing the first CTE stops the error but then gets no data found.

Not directly relevant but you can simplify your query, at least for the data you've shown, to a single XMLTable call:

```
SELECT au.xml_id,
       x.tran_ts as chg_timestr,
       to_date(substr(x.tran_ts, 0, 8), 'yyyymmdd') chg_date,
       cast(substr(x.tran_ts, 9, 6) as int) chg_time,
       x.fieldname,
       x.ov old_value,
       x.nv new_value
FROM myxml au
CROSS JOIN xmltable('/xml/entry/field'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(au.x)
  COLUMNS tran_ts   VARCHAR2(16) PATH './../@timestamp',
          fieldname VARCHAR2(250) PATH '@name',
          nv VARCHAR2(250) PATH 'nv',
          ov VARCHAR2(250) PATH 'ov'
) x;

    XML_ID CHG_TIMESTR      CHG_DATE     CHG_TIME FIELDNAME  OLD_VALUE  NEW_VALUE 
---------- ---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 20170330100429   2017-03-30     100429 Name       Fran       Frank     
         1 20170330100429   2017-03-30     100429 Zip        13583      13853     
         1 20170401094783   2017-04-01      94783 MI         J          A         
         1 20170401094783   2017-04-01      94783 Suffix     Jr         III
```

Trying to self-join that gets data, but lots of nulls. Also strange.

But even if your real query is too complicated to do that (you said you'd stripped it down, after all), you said the aim is get the most recent update, which you can do with:

```
with myxml as
(
  select /*+ materialize */ 1 xml_id,
         '<xml> <entry timestamp="20170330100429" effective="20170329"> <field name="Name"> <ov><![CDATA[Fran]]></ov> <nv><![CDATA[Frank]]></nv> </field> <field name="Zip"> <ov><![CDATA[13583]]></ov> <nv><![CDATA[13853]]></nv> </field> </entry> <entry timestamp="20170401094783" effective="20170331"> <field name="MI"> <ov><![CDATA[J]]></ov> <nv><![CDATA[A]]></nv> </field> <field name="Suffix"> <ov><![CDATA[Jr]]></ov> <nv><![CDATA[III]]></nv> </field> </entry> </xml>' x from dual
),
HRH as
(
  SELECT au.xml_id,
         x.tran_ts as chg_timestr,
         to_date(substr(x.tran_ts, 0, 8), 'yyyymmdd') chg_date,
         cast(substr(x.tran_ts, 9, 6) as int) chg_time,
         x.fieldname,
         x.ov old_value,
         x.nv new_value,
         rank() over (partition by au.xml_id, x.fieldname
           order by x.tran_ts desc) rnk
  FROM myxml au
  CROSS JOIN xmltable('/xml/entry/field'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(au.x)
    COLUMNS tran_ts   VARCHAR2(16) PATH './../@timestamp',
            fieldname VARCHAR2(250) PATH '@name',
            nv VARCHAR2(250) PATH 'nv',
            ov VARCHAR2(250) PATH 'ov'
  ) x
)
select * from HRH
where rnk = 1;
```

As you only have one set of data for each ID/field that gives you same result with your sample, but should give you the most recent for each if there are multiples. You should also look at the difference between the `rank()` and `dense_rank()` analytic functions, and decide what you want to see if there are ties - if that's possible in your data.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was with my query, but both of your queries work, and also allow me to perform the self-join, although I'm going to go with the second query you gave and eliminate the need for it.